# Lights not working after replacement

Tags: electrical

I have 5 lights all have their own switch. 2 upstairs 3 downstairs all run off the same circuit. I replaced the downstairs light first. Checked to see if it worked and it did. So I moved upstairs replaced the light up stairs and it also worked. Went downstairs and have no power to 3 of the lights and the outlets don't work either.

I put in the old fixture and now that doesn't work either. I am not a expert by any means.

Here is a photo of the downstairs light.

Edit
After checking the bundles again i get 120v when touching the black bundle to ground. Also getting 120v when checking the white bundle to ground. I must not have been touching the white proper when checking the 1st time. There is no power to the fixture or to the switch that controlled the light either.

[image: downstairs light fixture]
After messing with the two fixtures and ensuring I didn't have a loose wire. (It kept showing open neutral). Turns out it was a plug outlet that was the problem. When I had first checked the plug with the tester it told me it was correct. When I pulled the outlet out the burnt wire pulled out of the backstabbed outlet. Thanks everyone for their help. [image: burnt wire on outlet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watching the photo, it looks like you've connected to 'permanent' live and 'switched' live. To fix swap the black coming from the light with the white (coming from the light), then connect the white (coming from the light) to the other whites (bottom left in the photo). Your system doesn't have a 'red' cable (mandatory by new standard but allowed by the former) and is also 'reverse wired' (has a white as switched live instead of black as switched live)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information on getting that switch back together. My neighbor had stopped by to help me while i was at work and disconnected it. I didn't know how it went back together.

Answer (score 1):

There must have been some wire splices in the junction boxes of the upstairs lights that were disturbed when you installed the new fixture.  Take the last fixture down (the one installed before the downstairs lights failed) and look at the other wire connections.  If there is a bundle of wires (or two bundles), take off the wire nuts and make sure everything is tight and twist on a new wire nut.  Of course, all the power should be off when you do this as you will be in contact with multiple wires.

If you don't find any bundles, take down the next fixture you installed and check that junction box.  Home electric fixtures are never wired in series, so one fixture working shouldn't depend on another being installed.

Comment: I took down the last light i installed. Which is the light that still works checked the connections put on new wire nuts. This one does have a red wire instead of a black wire. The black wire runs to a bundle of black wires. There is only one switch to the light. Not sure if it matters. Still nothing to the downstairs lights. So do I move on and check the other light?

Comment: @Matt yea, I think so.  Something had to happen in one of those boxes. Was anyone else working on any other electrical boxes?  Even changing an outlet could have disturbed a connection.

Comment: No it was just me.

Comment: Ok i took apart the light downstairs and checked the bundles. Replaced the wire nuts. I did notice on the light upstairs the line with the black red white and ground wire. The black goes to the black bundle the red to the black wire on light. The white runs to the white bundle then a spare wire runs from the bundle to the white line on the light. By spare wire i mean if i take it out of both wire nuts i would have a 5" piece of non bare copper wire.

Comment: The light downstairs has a black bundle and a white bundle. They are just in the box. Then the line for the light goes black to black white to white and the ground.

Comment: I notice you say the outlets and the lights don't work downstairs... I assume you're checking the breakers and there isn't one that is off?  The low voltage you claim can happen if there is a hot wire with power going to it, but the neutral isn't connected all the way back to the breaker box.  The meter will read a phantom voltage.  I assume you're measuring the voltage between the black and white wires?  Whats the measurement between black and ground?  White and ground should be zero volts because they are bonded in the panel.

Comment: This is @Matt but to answer your comment I am getting 120V from black to ground on the bundle. Nothing on white to ground on white bundle. Nothing to the light nothing to the switch or outlets now. Here is a photo of the downstairs light. ![downstairs light fixture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muMOd.jpg)